# I wanted to dynamically import images but I run the project I do not see the images

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was creating react project and decided to escape create-react-app and create own custom template. So, then I wanted to dynamically add images via import like this

```
import picture1 from "../../assets/picture1.jpg";
import picture3 from "../../assets/picture3.jpg";
import picture5 from "../../assets/picture5.jpg";
```

So, to achieve that I installed file-loader and url-loader and set up the webpack config like this:

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = {
  // webpack will take the files from ./src/index
  entry: "./src/index",

  // and output it into /dist as bundle.js
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "/build"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
  },

  // adding .ts and .tsx to resolve.extensions will help babel look for .ts and .tsx files to transpile
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"],
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        enforce: "pre",
        use: [
          {
            options: {
              eslintPath: require.resolve("eslint"),
            },
            loader: require.resolve("eslint-loader"),
          },
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      // we use babel-loader to load our jsx and tsx files
      {
        test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },

      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "url-loader",
            options: {
              limit: 8192,
            },
          },
        ],
      },

      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
          },
        ],
      },

      // css-loader to bundle all the css files into one file and style-loader to add all the styles  inside the style tag of the document
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
    }),
  ],
};
```

So, pls let me know if I did everything right? Why don't I see the image when I run the project?

Comment: Looks like your using the url-loader and the file-loader for the same thing. Personally I use the file-loader. So just remove the url-loader. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ahh, I read the documentation a bit more. file-loader will copy the image to dist and then the code will refference the url. Where as the url-loader converts the file into a data url that will be included in the js bundle. Which may be what you were going for.

Comment: Can you add the ```HTML``` code where the image URL is added?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the file-loader and use the url-loader instead. Including the limit option will cause all files over 8192 bytes to use file-loader. So including the file loader rule is redundant. Furthermore anything under 8192 will be converted into a data url and included in the bundle.js.

I would do something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  rules: {
    {
      test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            mimetype: 'image/png',
            limit: 8192
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```